# jhipster hot reload failed to register liquibase changelog directory

Tags: directory, liquibase, changelog, jhipster

i just started using jhipster and face a problem already,

here's my development stack : 
- os windows 7 
- eclipse Juno 
- maven 3.1 
- latest node and npm 
- mysql as db in ubuntu vm

and here's what i have done : 
- generate jhipster "yo jhipster" 
- convert it to maven project "mvn eclipse:eclipse" 
- maven compile "mvn clean" & "mvn install" 
- add jhipster-reload feature in eclipse run vm arguments 
- and run the main class in eclipse "right click Application.java and run as java application" 
- generate new entity yo jhipster:entity ala 
- everything was pretty much generated for this new entity, only the liquibase changelog doesn't generated 
- i try to recompile the maven from eclipse then i found the line below 
[ERROR] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Failed to register the directory 'target\classes\config\liquibase\changelog'
- AFAIK it seems to be the same bug [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/310), but they says it's fixed

Thanks for anyone that could help this, i'm confused as what to do here as i'm new to jhipster, liquibase, hot reload concept, and the documentation or google search barely help as jhipster is relatively still young.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not use "mvn eclipse:eclipse"** in jhipster projects.
Just import the project as **existing Maven project**.

See [this](http://jhipster.github.io/configuring_ide_eclipse.html).