# Entity creation with Hot Reload doesn't generate liquibase changelog

Tags: jhipster

I have a problem similar to [jhipster hot reload failed to register liquibase changelog directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447872/jhipster-hot-reload-failed-to-register-liquibase-changelog-directory).

This has worked in the past, but I have never been able to get entity creation working correctly: "old" entities (from before the last restart) would fail through a missing table, and "new" entities becuase there was no service (`Did not find handler method for [/app/rest/foo3s]`)

I think I have all the latest versions (generator-jhipster 0.18.1 and `<jhipster-loaded.version>0.11</jhipster-loaded.version>`. I am running Oracle Java 7 within a Docker container on Debian Testing.

I can build and run the sample app (from `/jhipster`), but when I  try:

```
yo jhipster:entity foo5
```

I get:

```
The entity foo5 is being created.
appPath: src/main/webapp
appPath: src/main/webapp
appPath: src/main/webapp
create src/main/java/petemiller/domain/Foo5.java
create src/main/java/petemiller/repository/Foo5Repository.java
create src/main/java/petemiller/web/rest/Foo5Resource.java
create src/main/webapp/views/foo5s.html
create src/main/webapp/scripts/foo5/router_foo5.js
create src/main/webapp/scripts/foo5/controller_foo5.js
create src/main/webapp/scripts/foo5/service_foo5.js
create src/test/java/petemiller/web/rest/Foo5ResourceTest.java
jhipster@a3c758365d1b:/jhipster$
```

But there is no `db-changelog-00x.xml` file generated in the changelog folder, so of course, nothing else works.

Hot Reload seems to be ok, as on startup I get:

```
[INFO] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterReloaderAutoConfiguration - Spring Loaded is running, registering hot reloading features
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.reloader.JacksonReloader - Hot reloading Jackson enabled
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.reloader.LiquibaseReloader - Hot reloading JPA & Liquibase enabled
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.reloader.SpringReloader - Hot reloading Spring Beans enabled
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/i18n' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/templates' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/config' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/config/liquibase' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/config/liquibase/changelog' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/mails' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/mails/messages' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/repository' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/domain' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/domain/util' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web/filter' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web/filter/gzip' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web/rest' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web/rest/dto' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/web/propertyeditors' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/config' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/config/locale' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/config/apidoc' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/config/metrics' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/config/audit' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/security' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/aop' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/aop/logging' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/service' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/service/util' will be monitored for changes
[DEBUG] io.github.jhipster.loaded.JHipsterFileSystemWatcher - Directory : 'target/classes/petemiller/async' will be monitored for changes
[INFO] petemiller.Application - Started Application in 19.546 seconds (JVM running for 20.322)
```

I have done a Maven clean and everything else I can think of, like checking permissions, etc

Suggestions for next steps, anyone?

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with the latest generator version. I get Hot Reload enabled message but no db changelog is generated so the app is worthless!